# Passing std::vector to array reference

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem trying to interface some old-school C++ code with more modern data structures. **Unfortunately I can't change the old code's interface so I'm stuck with the functions as written**

In particular, there is a function that takes the following as a parameter:

```
int doStuff(FooObj* (&foo_array), int n_elements) {
  // do stuff with array member 0
  FooObj* foo = &(foo_array[0])
 ... 
}
```

Basically the way this function is used in the legacy code is a pointer to an array of FooObj is created on the heap, then passed to the function:

```
FooObj* foos;
foos = new FooObj[100];
doStuff(foos, 100);
delete [] foos;
```

What I want to do is pass in a vector of FooObj (because the contents will be sized dynamically) but I'm having trouble understanding the pointer/reference semantics. If I try the following:

```
std::vector<FooObj> foos;
foos.resize(100);
doStuff(&foos[0], 100);
```

I get the error: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'FooObj*&' from a temporary of type 'FooObj*'`

Is it possible to pass a vector like this?

Comment: your `doStuff()` declaration doesn't support `vector<>`. You need to change the signature and also change the implementation to use vector. Remember that you are using Vector<FooObj*>

Comment: `&foos[0]` is an rvalue and rvalues cannot bind to lvalue-references. You shouldn't even be doing this in the first place. Just use a parameter of type `std::vector<FooObj>&`

Comment: Okay, one thing I didn't make clear though is that I can't touch the doStuff method.

Comment: Then you need to shoot the person who wrote it because, unless it actually modifies `foo_array` (which is a pointer, not an array), it's totally pointless. Try `FooObj *temp = &foos[0];` and pass temp

Comment: Agreed :) The code is really horrible; this isn't the half of it. Anyway, passing the temp does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with heap versus stack. An approximate rule of thumb: when passing a parameter that's declared as a reference, you have to pass an lvalue. So:

```
std::vector<FooObj> foos;
foos.resize(100);

FooObj *p=&foos[0];

doStuff(p, 100);
```

The reason you were getting a compiler error is because the expression "`&foos[0]`" is an rvalue, and you have to stick an lvalue in here. So: make this an lvalue.